# how can I modify variable value by entering variable name in JS function parameter

Tags: javascript

```
var myValue = 0 ;
// function that add 5 to the variable that i type its name in the function parameters .
function modifyVariable(variableName){
    variableName += 4
}
modifyVariable(myValue);
console.log(myValue);
```

now the variable value still 0 not 5 .

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `myValue` is storing a Number, and JavaSript passes Numbers by value. Store the value in an object instead since JavaScript passes objects by reference...

```js
var myValue = {v: 0} ;

// function that add 5 to the variable that i type its name in the function parameters .
function modifyVariable(obj) {
    obj.v += 4
}

modifyVariable(myValue);
console.log(myValue.v);
```

You can read more about how JS passes objects [here](https://medium.com/nodesimplified/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c)